# How to source multiple workspaces from the same terminal?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to launch two different nodes from two different workspaces from the same terminal. But once I source my terminal with one of the workspaces, I am not able to use the other packages since the other workspace directory is not sourced anymore.

Even though I saw this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/205976/sourcing-from-multiple-workspaces/), it doesn't work for me, maybe since I am using catkin build. Also, I don't want to keep deleting my `build`, `devel` spaces.

I have noticed that it may be possible to assign priority of search to ros as two `setup.zsh` are already sourced `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.zsh` and one of my workspaces. `ROS` seems to be assigning priority to these while searching for packages.

Can anyone please explain me how sourcing of `setup.zsh` files work? And how can I find a workaround to my problem or preferably use the method used by ROS itself

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327791/how-to-source-multiple-workspaces-from-the-same-terminal?/) by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2019-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With catkin, the last sourced `setup.(z/ba)sh` wins. Thus, there is no assignment of priorities or something similar, other than way how you build your workspace.

As explained in detail in #q64702, you can "extend" one workspace with another. But this is a rather unusual usage, from my experience.

More typical is to use "workspace chaining", which is specifying the order of the search path for ROS packages.
The answer you linked does explain this behavior, and [this](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) is the link to the respective tutorial.

Using `catkin_tools` this is also doable, though you can/need to be more explicit! The chaining (you also chain the `/opt/ros` and your source ws, let's call it `~/catkin_ws` when working with only one ws) happens implicitely when you have sourced `/opt/ros/DISTRO/setup.zsh` and call `catkin init` for the first time. This is what you see in the output of `catkin config` under the "Extending" listing in `catkin_ws`.

To change which ws you are extending, simply call `catkin config --extend /path/to/new/ws` in the workspace that you want to overlay/extend over the others. I.e. if you want to overlay `~/overlay_ws` over `~/catkin_ws`, call

```
cd ~/overlay_ws
catkin config --extend ~/catkin_ws/devel
catkin clean # there is no way around deleting your build/devel folders when changing chaining
catkin b
```

Note that deleting `devel` and `build` is required for this to work, but only when changing the chaining.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3